# 0000-00-00 00:00:00 datetime is showing incorrectly in magento admin grid filter

Tags: grid, filter, date

I am using datetime grid filter in my custom module grid. I use following code-

```
$this->addColumn('created_at', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('po')->__('Created At'),
            'align' => 'center',
            'width' => '10px',
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'index' => 'created_at',
        ));
```

if a row in database contains datetime  **0000-00-00 00:00:00** then the value in grid column is showing **Nov 30, -1 5:30:00 AM** besides showing **0000-00-00 00:00:00**. but if a row in DB contains a value in datetime column then exact time is being shown in grid column.  How it can be corrected.?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change default value of your field to be a NULL in database.

Default datetime value should not be 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in database.

Comment: It is showing error "Invalid default value for 'created_at' " if I edit created_at column in DB with default value NULL.

Comment: and what if I want  to show datetime 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: you will need to create custom renderer